# Solve for $x$; $\sin(2x)=\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{8}); 0< x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Question:   Solve for $x$; 
$$\sin(2x)=\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{8}); 0< x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I tried  but couldn’t get it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2x = x + \dfrac{\pi}{8}+ 2n\pi \to x = \dfrac{\pi}{8} + 2n\pi \to n = 0 \to x = \dfrac{\pi}{8}$

Also $2x = \pi - \left(x+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\right) + 2n\pi \to 3x = \dfrac{7\pi}{8} + 2n\pi \to x = \dfrac{7\pi}{24} + \dfrac{2n\pi}{3} \to n = 0 \to x = \dfrac{7\pi}{24}$

Answer (score 1):

if $$\sin 2x = \sin x + \pi/8, $$ then  $$2x = x + \pi/8 + 2k\pi, \pi - x - \pi/8 + 2k\pi \to x = \pi/8+2k\pi, x = 7\pi/24+2k\pi/3.$$   we can pick up the solutions in the interval $0 \le x \le \pi/2$ as $$x = \pi/8, 7\pi/24. $$